# Wordpress tags redirect to subdomains

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I've a Wordpress blog and I'd like to redirect some tags to a subdomain.
I've created the subdomain in the admin panel of my host.

Example:
http://www.myblog.com/tag/numberone
http://numberone.myblog.com

I've tried with this code but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^tag/numberone
RewriteRule ^tag/numberone/(.*)$ http://numberone.myblog.com/$1 [R]
```

I've also tried the Wp-Subdomains plugin but it doesn't work with Wordpress 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) to link to the subdomain.

Create a file called **tag-numberone.php** and place it inside the theme directory.

Inside this file put the following code:

```
<?php wp_redirect('http://numberone.myblog.com', 301); exit; ?>
```

This code will use the wordpress function `wp_redirect` to direct you to the subdomain you require and also add in the HTTP redirect status (301 for permanent redirects, 302 for temporary).

This should do the trick. You can also create a file for each tag you want to redirect with by using the *slug* of the tag in the filename:
**tag-tag1_slug.php**, **tag-tag2_slug.php**, etc.

Comment: I don't think that this solution match my case.
I'd like also to use the subdomain for navigate all the sub-pages of the tag, for example:
http://numberone.myblog.com/2/
instead of http://myblog.colm/tag/numberone/2/